# Temporary Voice Channels in Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have following working code in C# and using Discord.Net but i dont know what i need to do, to delete the
temporary created channel when no user is in the channel. **I know how to delete a channel but i dont know how to check if the old channel is the temporary created channel.
I need to check if the old channel is the temp created one and delete it when no user is in the channel but only this channel and not every channel else.**

This is my working code so far

```
            _client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += HandleVoiceState;

    }
    public async Task HandleVoiceState(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState before, SocketVoiceState after)
    {
            Console.WriteLine($"VoiceStateUpdate: {user} - {before.VoiceChannel?.Name ?? "null"} -> {after.VoiceChannel?.Name ?? "null"}");
            //needs await
        if (user is SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser)
        {
            var server = socketGuildUser.Guild;

            var categoryId = server.CategoryChannels.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Name.Equals(" Staff "))?.Id;
            

            if (socketGuildUser.VoiceState?.VoiceChannel.Id == 856855859001557012)
            {
                var voiceChannel = await server.CreateVoiceChannelAsync(socketGuildUser.Username, prop => prop.CategoryId = categoryId);
                Console.WriteLine(voiceChannel.Id);
                await socketGuildUser.ModifyAsync(x =>
                {
                    x.Channel = Optional.Create(voiceChannel as IVoiceChannel);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                            var usersVoiceChannel = (socketGuildUser as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel;
                    if (usersVoiceChannel == null)

                        {
                        if ((after.VoiceChannel != before.VoiceChannel)
                                && before.VoiceChannel.Category.Id.Equals(autocreatecategoryid) 
                                && before.VoiceChannel.Users.Count == 0 
                                && !before.VoiceChannel.Id.Equals(autocreateid))
                            {
                                await before.VoiceChannel.DeleteAsync();
                            } 
                        }else{
                            if (!(before.VoiceChannel == null)
                                && before.VoiceChannel.Category.Id.Equals(autocreatecategoryid) 
                                && before.VoiceChannel.Users.Count == 0 
                                && !before.VoiceChannel.Id.Equals(autocreateid))
                            {
                                await before.VoiceChannel.DeleteAsync();
                            } 
                        }
                        
                        
                            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).